# I have a file generated from Django, I need to send that file as response to frontend using drf?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

Using the python i have parsed a file and stored, now i need to send that file to my front end using drf as api view.

Can I send a file as a response like json response? If so how t send it?

Comment: First of all, it depends on what kind of file you are trying to serialize/return. If you are trying to return some kind of media file, it's not possible to serialize it properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example of sending a file using a `HttpResponse` (from `django.http`):

```
class ExportDataView(views.APIView):

    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, HasDashboardReadAccess)

    def get(self, request):
        # Read the data from your file (use with open(): or whatever else you need)
        file = <your_file>.read()
        # Specify the file content type (here it's an .xlsx)
        content_type = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
        response = HttpResponse(file, content_type=content_type)
        response['Content-Disposition'] = f'attachment; filename={<your file name>}'

        return response
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the file size and file type there are different techniques to achieve that.

For bigger files it's generally not recommended to use Django to serve them. If the resource is not access protected, I would serve the file as a media file or a static file and let front end retrieve it from there. If it's access protected, a common practice is to put file somewhere like S3 and [send a generated signed URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html).

For smaller payloads you can simply read file contents and send [a file attachment response](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#telling-the-browser-to-treat-the-response-as-a-file-attachment).

Comment: Can you provide any examples for file attachment response?

Comment: Check @henriquesalvaro answer +1

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but just like any other media, it will be sent in the form of a URL in JSON. In order to add the URL to your response, simply [serialize](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/) your data, and then send it as a [response](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/2-requests-and-responses/). You can then manipulate the file using whatever frontend language you use.